# Dotnet Linux Docker container works with Development config but not Local Config

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I am attempting to setup an ASP.Net core WebAPI project into a Linux Docker container.  It currently works fine outside of the container.

When I attempt to run the container locally, the API will not start and throw the following error when calling the `application.Run()` method.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.'
```

If I change the configuration environment in my docker-config file to point to my development testing environment's configuration settings, everything works just fine locally (though pointing to the testing environment's resources).

The container is a Linux container so it does not have access to `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`.  However, I feel like if it was a certificate issue, it wouldn't be "fixed" by just pointing it to different configuration settings simply by changing the `ASPNET_ENVIRONMENT` setting.

When setting up the configuration values for application, it pulls in the configuration settings from my development testing environment and then overrides them with settings in the local configuration file.  If I comment out all settings in the local configuration file, the same error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive troubleshooting and searching, I found the solution to this issue.

ASP.Net Core has a hardcoded, compiled setting where it sets up a default https cert when the environment is Development.  To update this setting for any other environment you wish to run in, you can add the following snippet into your `Program.cs` file.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) => {
    if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("LocalDocker"))
    {
        config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
    }
})
```